# What is the point in assigning head to a pointer 'p', and de-allocating 'p' after removal of head?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list

I found a function that deletes the head node of a Linked List and shifts the head to the next node. What is the use of assigning head to p, and after shifting head, de-allocating it, if one could just shift head and get the same result.

I just used printf("%d", head->data) and head = head->next, and got the same result. Am I wasting any memory?

```
// Why should I use this :
void deleteFromFront() {
    node p = head;
    printf("\n\tThe deleted element is : %d\n", head->data);
    head = head->next;
    free(p);
}

// And not this :
void deleteFromFront() {
    printf("\n\tThe deleted element is : %d\n", head->data);
    head = head->next;
}
```

Comment: In your second snippet, you're not deleting anything.

Comment: @Blaze But when I call the number of items in the list function and view all elements function, I'm getting the same results.

Comment: If you have a call to `malloc` to allocate memory, but don't have a corresponding call to `free`, then you have a *memory leak*.

Comment: *one could just shift head and get the same result.*  That would leak the memory allocated for the original `head` node.  You no longer have a reference to it, so it will remain allocated and unusable.  Do that enough times and you'll run out of memory.

Comment: As you move the head to head->next there is no way to access the previous node(previous head). If you do this the previous node's allocated memory is still there and will cause a memory leak. Storing head in p initially will allow you to free that memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version:

```
node p = head;
printf("\n\tThe deleted element is : %d\n", head->data);
head = head->next;
free(p);
```

free the old head node, and this version:

```
printf("\n\tThe deleted element is : %d\n", head->data);
head = head->next;
```

does not. The first version must be used if you want to free the old head node. If you `free` a piece of memory, it can be reused the next time you call `malloc`. If you don't `free` your memory when you're done with it, your program will use more and more memory because the system still thinks your program is using it. This is called a memory leak.